# start logstash from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, elasticsearch, logstash

Question: How can I start logstash from a script on my rails application?

Background: I have logstash and elasticsearch running on a server. I have a rails application which uploads a CSV to the server and logstash then processes. It works if I manually execute the generated script. If I try to have rails do a system command, I get an error.

Manually call the script from server (WORKS)

```
logstash_folder/execute_random.sh
```

Rails app system command(ERROR)

```
 `logstash_folder/execute_random.sh`
```

**Error: WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults**

execute_random.sh (script being called)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop logstash
sleep 1
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f logstash_folder/conf_folder/logstash.conf
```

Looking over this blog
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/warning-could-not-find-logstash-yml-which-is-typically-located-in-ls-home-config-or-etc-logstash/131022/15

I change the script to include `--path.settings`

```
  sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/ --path.data -f logstash_folder/#{self.logstash_index}/#{self.logstash_index}.conf"
```

& recieve this error

```
    ERROR: Unknown command 'logstash_folder/conf_folder/logstash.conf'
```

OR

```
    [INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in 
    path {:path=>"/logstash_folder/conf_folder/logstash.conf"}
    [ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] 
    No configuration found in the configured sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the command as a variable
example = "execute_#{index}"

and then setting that into backticks with a variable
execute_example = `example`
which didn't work

ended up using System("#{example}") and that worked...
3days of stress